# Running VPython on older Refurbished computers

Tags: graphics

I am trying to run VPython on my new refurbished Lenovo Thinkpad. Every program I run seems to calculate and print just fine, but there are no graphics being displayed. The black-screen window that usually pops up when running a program is not being displayed although my computer appears to be running through calculations. I am pretty sure I installed VPython correctly, and I'm pretty sure this is not a programming error.

Does anyone know anything about an incompatibility of older computers and VPython that I can look into?

P.S I think you can tell I'm pretty new to programming, but any help will be appreciated!